# Is there any way to hint the name Windows 10 should use for profile dirs?

Tags: microsoft-office-365, entra-id

When I sign a user into a machine that's joined to my Office 365 Azure AD for the first time, Windows creates a directory in `\Users` something along the lines of `FirstnameLastname`.

Nice as that is, I've always been accustomed to having control over this path and choosing a name that's quick and easy for me to type.  Say `atrauzzi` vs `AlexanderTrauzzi`.

Is there any kind of information I can associate with my Azure AD user that would result in Windows using a value I provide by default for the name of the profile directory on first login?